# Search for URL in large CSV file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CSV file containing 1 million URLs (it's the [Alexa top sites](http://www.alexa.com/topsites) file). I also have another list of URLs, I need to check if these exist in the topsites CSV.

**What are my options for doing this?**

I am considering importing the CSV into a MySQL temporary table, but this would make my solution less portable. **Is there any more portable alternative to MySQL?**.

Comment: Second list large as first one?

Comment: @HAL9000 No, the second list would be 1000 at the most

Comment: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) is an option ?

Comment: `grep 'http://example.com' file.csv`? But if you're going to be searching repeatedly, you'd be better off sucking the file into a database.

Comment: @MarcB: Or better yet, `grep -f /path/to/URLs /path/to/topsites` ?

Comment: @HAL9000 I think this might be slow, to loop through 1m lines in the CSV and then compare.